# Proof of work при снижении майнинга

Tags: алгоритм, bitcoin, криптовалюта

Часть криптовалют (в том числе биткоин) основаны на концепции proof of work. Самая длинная цепь побеждает, а гарантией подлинности транзакции является невозможность перемайнить достаточно длинный хвост за счёт того, что надо получить вдвое большую частоту генерации блоков (и старый кусок переписать и от новых по количеству не отстать). При этом сложность корректируется таким образом, чтобы интервал между созданием блоков был примерно одинаков.

Получается, что обладатель менее чем половиной майнящих устройств не сможет создавать блоки с вдвое большей скоростью, чем остальные участники, поэтому старые блоки в безопасности и подменить их практически нереально.

Эта схема очевидным образом работает при постоянном увеличении мощностей, когда сложность постоянно возрастает.

Но сейчас наоборот наблюдается спад майнинга и понижение сложности. Как именно proof of work обеспечивает безопасность старых блоков в таких ситуациях? Ведь физически способных майнить устройств меньше не становится - они просто перестают использоваться. Что мешает в таких условиях отойти на некоторое число шагов назад и перераспределить сложность на этом временном интервале, чтобы более ранние блоки были перегенерированы с меньшей сложностью?

Answer (score 1):

Что бы осуществить вашу задумку, сначала придется генерировать блоки реже, чем нужно по стандарту сети. Сгенерите меньше блоков - цепочка будет короче.

Вариант, что больше 50% всех майнеров сговорились - это получится просто атака 51%, такой случай я не рассматриваю.

Возьмем для примера биткоин. Допустим мы хотим понизить сложность в 10 раз. Хочу заметить, что для этого нам необходимо иметь 10% от мощности всей сети. Итак, мы откатываемся на 2 недели назад (интервал пересчета сложности), и начинаем майнить 1 блок в 100 минут. Что бы произошел пересчет сложности в нашей ветке, нам нужно намайнить 2016 блоков (2016 блоков это константа сети, при 10 минутах за блок получается ровно 2 недели). Нам нужно майнить 20 недель в своей ветке до уменьшения сложности в 10 раз, и мы намайним 2016 блоков. В это время правильная ветка намайнит 20000 блоков.

Если у группы людей меньше 50% мощностей, они не могут ничего сделать.

Comment: Уменьшение уже произошло - оно внешнее. Я не про подделку сложности, а про перераспределение. Например, если сложность понижалась (просто наугад называю, ни к сему реальному не привязано) как 2\*\*12, 2\*\*8, 2\*\*6 - усредняем эту штуку до каких-нибудь 2\*\*7 просто перераспределив количество блоков за каждый промежуток (но суммарное количество оставив неизменным). Причём пока мы это генерируем, сложность продолжает понижаться. По независящим от нас факторам.

Comment: @Qwertiy это все сработает только тогда, когда мощность отключенных майнеров станет больше, чем мощность сети, и они все сговорятся, и опять же получится атака 51%. Ваш пример очень нереалистичный, если группа майнеров с 2^7 начнет генерить блоки при сложности 2^12, они будут генерить их 32*2=64 недели, что бы перейти до пересчета (как у моем примере).

Comment: @Qwertiy на практике очень сильно сложность не может падать. Она не может падать быстрее чем падает цена. Цена упала в 2 раза - сложность упадет не больше чем в 2 раза. Так как при падении сложности ровно в 2 раза, все получают такую же награду как и раньше (в фиатных деньгах).

Comment: Я кажется не учёл, что перерасчёт происходит по числу блоков, а не по времени. А вот с временем что-то не понял. _"если группа майнеров с 2^7 начнет генерить блоки при сложности 2^12, они будут генерить их 32*2=64 недели"_ - одинаковое количество блоков при меньшей сложности наоборот сгенерируются быстрее (если рассматривать затраченное вычислительное время). Вот про цену интереснее. Но цена с максимума упала где-то раз в 7, если не ошибаюсь. Правда, давно он был этот максимум - вероятно, слишком давно, чтобы до него достать.

Comment: @Qwertiy я имел ввиду  "если группа майнеров *с сумарной мощностью* 2^7 начнет генерить блоки *при сложности сети* 2^12, они будут генерить их 32*2=64 недели". Да, максимум был давно, а сложность начала падать только относительно недавно, и то незначительно.